# create-next-app does not work, get internal server error

Tags: next.js

Need some advice on this. I have initialize a whole new project by using create-next-app:

```
npx create-next-app nextjs-app
```

I was able to start the project by calling npm run dev. This is what i have in the terminal when run on the development server:

```
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
```

However, i get internal server error when navigate to localhost:3000. There is this error on the terminal:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

I am running on node v12.16.3 and npm v6.14.4